# Why doesn't use server work in Next.js 13.4?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I wrote a function by declaring use server with code like this,

Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options

I keep getting this error.

What could be the reason?

```js
import { cookies } from "next/dist/client/components/headers";

type SearchParams = {
  searchParams: {
    code: string;
  };
};

export default async function EmailLoginPage({ searchParams }: SearchParams) {
  await testCookie();

  async function testCookie() {
    "use server";
    cookies().set("test", "test");
  }

  return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks, but It occurs same problem. Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.

There are two things are going wrong here:

1. You're importing `cookies` wrong.
2. Server Actions can only be called using the `action` or `formAction` prop.

Here's the updated code:

```js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

type SearchParams = {
  searchParams: {
    code: string;
  };
};

export default async function EmailLoginPage({ searchParams }: SearchParams) {

  async function testCookie() {
    "use server";
    cookies().set("test", "test");
  }

  return (
    <form action={testCookie}>
      <input placeholder="email" name="email" type="text" autofocus required/>
      <input placeholder="password" name="password" type="password" required/>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Read more about [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions).

Comment: Thanks, but It occurs same problem.

Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options

Comment: @gndy I updated the answer to address the issue.